# What is the difference between LocalDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter) and DateTimeFormatter.format(TemporalAccessor)?

Tags: java, date, java-time

In the Java 8 DateTime API, there are 2 ways to format a date that at first glance seem to do the same thing:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm").format(LocalDateTime.now());
LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"));
```

These both return a String representing the date and time at runtime.

Is there a significant difference between these 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they're equivalent - and they're even *documented* to be equivalent, at least for the default implementation. [`ChronoLocalDateTime.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoLocalDateTime.html#format(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter)) includes this:

> The default implementation must behave as follows:
>
> ```
> return formatter.format(this);
> ```

Sometimes one form is useful, sometimes the other is - it can depend on what you're chaining together in a longer expression.

Comment: Good to know. As an aside, don't you think it's weird that it's taken until now for someone to ask this question here? I would have expected someone to ask this question sooner.